# Set text of Text Field from content of ResultSet

Tags: java

i have been trying a lot of syntax but i can't figured it out.
I want to display "Invoice number" from my databases to the text field (The field "invoice" from table "transaksi" is already filled with number) But it won't show anything. Here's my code :

```
private void InvoiceActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   ResultSet aa = null;
    try {   
    koneksi objKoneksi = new koneksi();
        Connection kon = objKoneksi.bukaKoneksi();
        Statement stat = kon.createStatement();
    String query ="select invoice from transaksii";
    String res = aa.getString(query);
    Invoice.setText(res);
   }
   catch (SQLException e) {}
}
```

Note : - Invoice is Former JTextField1.
       - transaksii = name of my table.
       - invoice = name of the field.

Thank you. English is not my native language.

Comment: Where are you actually executing the query? Where exactly have you written this line `ResultSet rSet = stat.executeQuery(query)`? One you have a result set, only then you can iterate over it, to get a `String` value, like `String res = rs.getString( Either column Name(String) or Column Number (int) );;` Please, do look into this part, also

Comment: @Rainzo78 From your original post I would say if there are more than 1 row in the table it will return many numbers. Now which number do you want to display in the `Invoice`  text field?

Answer (score 1):

You did not execute the query. The value of `aa` is null and you might be getting a `NullPointerException`.

```
String query ="select invoice from transaksii";
aa=stat.executeQuery(query);
if(aa.next())
String res = aa.getString("invoice");
```

Note: Its not a good practice to have an empty `catch` because you would then end up without knowing about the exception like now. You should do `e.printStackTrace();` in catch block.

Comment: post the stacktrace if there are any exception ,did you print the exception?

Comment: Sorry for bad english. What is print exception? and how to post StackTrace?

Comment: try changing the catch to `catch (Exception e)`   and then check the console

Comment: wait a sec. the field "invoice" are integer. Do i have to change it to VarChar?

Comment: @Rainzo78 I don't think it will help to change to VARCHAR.

Comment: @Blip : I guess i can't change to varchar because i want use Auto increment. You have any suggestion to my problem above?

Comment: no dont change just try printing the the string in console to verify if you are getting correct output

Comment: @singhakash It shows nothing. And the text field Invoice still empty.

Comment: change  catch to `catch (Exception e)` then add `if(aa.next())`(I have edited my answer )

Comment: @Rainzo78 From your original post I would say if there are more than 1 row in the table it will return many numbers. Now which number do you want to display in the `Invoice` text field?

Comment: did you print the string in console what is the value of string you are getting?

Comment: @Blip : I just filled the table with one row of data. That means only one number in invoice.

Comment: @singhakash if what you mean with "print the string in console" is "System.out.print(res)", the answer is nothing. Console shows nothing.

Comment: Note : i put that "System.out.print(res)" in same structure of Private void

Answer (score 1):

There is only 1 problem in your original code. The result set that has returned in the line `aa = stat.executeQuery(query);` is presently at the a position before the 1st result returned. So When you call `aa.getString` it is not going to return any thing as it is before the 1st result. Also the `ResultSet.getString` takes a parameter of `int` or a parameter of `String` representing the column name. But in your case you have passed the query as the parameter.

So the corrected code should be if you only want to return the 1st item of the `ResultSet` would be :

```
private void InvoiceActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   ResultSet aa = null;
    try {   
    koneksi objKoneksi = new koneksi();
        Connection kon = objKoneksi.bukaKoneksi();
        Statement stat = kon.createStatement();
        String query ="select invoice from transaksii";
        aa = stat.executeQuery(query);
        String res = "";
        if(aa.next()){ // checks and moves it to 1st position
           res = aa.getString("invoice"); //column name of the column
        }
        Invoice.setText(res);
   }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
        //The closing of connection, statement and resultset.
   }
}
```

Comment: @Rainzo78 You did not try my code put above. Did you? I mentioned of the problems in details did you look into those? You have called `aa.next()` two time. that results to the pointer in the resultset going to 2nd position which is again empty.

Comment: if i type : if(aa.hasNext), detected as error cannot find symbols method hasNext

Comment: i deleted the first ResultSet aa = null, because it causes an error (multiple declaration).

Comment: And it still the same =(

Comment: @Rainzo78 Ok from your comments to the above answer I see that your debug using `System.out.println(res)` had returned "". So, your problem is not with the java code but with the query. Have you tried the query in the database? what does it return.

Comment: I've try Select invoice from transaksii in query. It returns a number "1".
I have something to say that even i change Invoice.setText("5"), the textfield still empty. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: @Rainzo78 This is a very unusual problem. How have you initialised Invoice?

Comment: @Rainzo78 I want to know of the code like `JTextField invoice = new JTextField()` something like that somewhere in your code that you have not posted.

Comment: Only find this on bottom of the code : private javax.swing.JTextField Invoice;